# Will Salesforce process builder reevaluate every time a change is made on field X?

Tags: process-builder, field-update, scheduled-job, scheduled

I have a custom account lookup field "account_reference__c" and a date field  "reference_date__c", any time the "account_reference__c" changes a workflow updates the "reference_date__c" with TODAY. I want to use the process builder to check, anytime the reference_date__c is changed, start a scheduled field update 6 months ahead. in 6 months time it should set the field "update_reference__c" to true. if however the reference date has changed to a later date i want it to reevaluate and start counting 6 months from the new date and not trigger the update_reference__c to true on the previously set day for the field update. 
So in short, my question is.

1. Would the process builder reevaluate before doing the update six months later?
2. Would the old process be canceled?
3. Would a new process be queued for the new date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers in order

1. Yes the process builder would need to reevaluate as the field that is used to trigger it has changed.
2. The old process would be cancelled
3. Yes a new process would be queued with the new date.

This is dependent on the process builder having the settings with

> Start the process when the record is created or edited on the Object
>   Advanced Settings - Do you want to execute the actions only when
>   specified changes are made to the record?

In the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US) it states

> For processes that are set to run when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for that record from the queue.
>
> For processes that are set to run when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record with that process. Scheduled actions remain in the queue, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria when the scheduled actions are executed.

You can see the waiting interviews (future actions from processes) on the **Flows** section

Setup>Build>Create>Workflow & Approvals>Flows

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so to confirm, When edited it will also delete the old process and create a new one in its place six months from that day. Correct?

Comment: Yes, it should do that. You can see the waiting flows in the paused and waiting interviews on the flow page.