# Update version of Process Builder and Pending Scheduled Actions

Tags: process-builder, schedule

I would like to know what happen when I have some Scheduled Action for  version 1 of Process Builder A and I make some changes in the same Process Builder and activate version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do changes to the same process - you must clone it and then activate it to then replace the current process.
[image]

The other option is to Deactivate it and then create a new process, however, if you do this.

> After you deactivate a process, the scheduled actions continue as
>   usual. If a deactivated process has pending scheduled actions and the
>   record whose field the schedule is based on is changed, Salesforce
>   recalculates the schedule for those actions.

You should probably go through [Considerations for Scheduling Process Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&language=en_US&type=0) and update your post with your specific use case along any inconsistent behavior or the part in the documentation you don't understand based on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that  you have clone it and activate the clone. And doing this, what happen with scheduled actions for previous version

Comment: A soon as you activate your version 2, the action defined for version 2 will take effect. While doing so, actions for version 1 will take precedence.

Comment: So you mean that actions for version 1 and version 2 can take place at the same time in the queue?

Comment: noooo- i never said that

Comment: Please view updated answer and update your question or post a new one to not mix up multiple questions in one post within comments.

Comment: Sorry but for me your answer was unclear.

Comment: How is your question different than https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138009/will-salesforce-process-builder-reevaluate-every-time-a-change-is-made-on-field. Did you check out the question prior to posting this one? maybe you can add some context/use case to your question?

Answer (score 3):

I interpret the question to mean: what happens when an individual record is in `Paused Flow Interview` state, and a new version of the PB is published?

[image]

The record will wake up at its scheduled time and complete its steps **according to the version that was active when the timer started**.

Full details of my test: https://www.stupidcrmtricks.com/2020/08/what-happens-to-inflight-process.html

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this question [**here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312305/process-builder-scheduled-processes-in-previous-versions). You can read it for the TL DR; version

Otherwise -

1. If your organization has matured/unchanging SLA's defined, then **Move** your Time-Based process nodes into a **separate process chain** so that they dont get cloned everytime you make changes/introduce new immediate action nodes **-OR-**
2. Remove the time-based process nodes and replace with individual time-based **workflows** instead since they dont have the versioning issue.

Answer (score -1):

Process Builder executes only active version and ignore previous inactive versions. Though all the versions will be saved for historical tracking purposes.

Only one version can be active at a time.

If there are any actions performed by previous scheduled action and it is pending to be executed then still that will in the queue. When you activate new version, any changes to the record will take the latest version.

Refer [Automate Business Process with Process Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder) Trailhead

**Consider the following when creating automated processes.**

- You can reorder criteria nodes—just drag and drop them. However, you can’t change the order of actions. After you add actions, the only way to reorder them is to delete them and start over.
- If you create processes to replace any workflow rules, make sure you delete or deactivate those workflow rules when you activate the equivalent processes. Otherwise, both workflow rules and processes fire and cause unexpected results, such as overwritten records or redundant email messages.
- You can add scheduled actions only if the process starts when a record is created, or if the process starts when a record is created or edited and you select Yes when asked “Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?”
- A process can have up to 50 versions, but only one version of a process can be active.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I know that Process Builder executes only active version. In my question I would like to mean that what happens with Scheduled actions assuming that I create a new version and activate it.

Comment: if there are any actions performed by previous scheduled action and it is pending to be executed then still that will in the queue. When you activate new version, any changes to the record will take the latest version

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I'm not sure that it is the behaviour. What happen if the new version of Process Builder stablish another new Scheduled Action. Could you tell me in which part of Salesforce documentation have you found that? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I have updated ans including this link https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder

Comment: Thanks Santany but there is general documentation about Process Builder that I knew before

Comment: if you are not sure about expected behavior then do some POC and verify the outcome

Comment: Santanu -- I'm not sure your answer is correct - see Bob Hatcher's answer and [his experiment](https://www.stupidsalesforcetricks.com/2020/08/what-happens-to-inflight-process.html?showComment=1620951937334#c8737820663597225861) - the paused flow interviews will execute using the flow/pb version at the moment of pausing.