# Do Process Builder Scheduled Actions re-evaluate the criteria before firing?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

If I have a set of criteria in the blue diamond:

1. `Status` = `Sent`
2. Person = X
3. Room = Y

And there are some immediate actions and 3 Scheduled Actions that happen at 24, 46 and 48 hours after a date-time field on the object.

If the `Status` is updated to `Paid` before the third scheduled action has fired, will the Scheduled Actions still get fired?

Comment: Did you look into [Will Salesforce process builder reevaluate every time a change is made on field X?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138009/will-salesforce-process-builder-reevaluate-every-time-a-change-is-made-on-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheduled actions whose criteria are no longer valid prior to their scheduled execution time are removed from the queue, provided the Process is executed on both creation and editing of the record.

From [How Does Salesforce Process Scheduled Actions?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5):

> For processes that start when a record is created or edited, scheduled actions remain in the queue only as long as the criteria for those actions are still valid. If a record no longer matches the criteria, Salesforce removes the scheduled actions for the record from the queue.

However,

> For processes that start when a record is created, Salesforce never reevaluates the record with that process. Scheduled actions remain in the queue, even if the record no longer meets the associated criteria when the scheduled actions are executed.